# Bootstrap left/right aligned background image repeat-pattern with 100% page height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, templating

So i'm building a bootstrap template and the problem I've encountered is trying to add a background image aligned to left side of site and a duplicate on the right side, it's like a small 40px width repeat-height type of pattern.

It is written like this and I know that is stupid but I've tried combinations of things and inside the bootstrap container, outside, etc.

```
#background-right {
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}

.containerbackgroundright {
background-image: url("../images/subtle_stripes.png");
height: auto;
max-width: 50px;
min-width: 0;
position: relative;
right: -15%;
}
```

ignore the stupid way I wrote that out. It is currently right after the `<body>` and before the `<container>`.  What happens is the height of the repeat background only reaches about 75% of the page most times depending on how far the container stretches with the content of that page. It isn't the full 100% of the page.

If I change the `position:` to `fixed` it actually works but produces unwanted results because I don't want it fixed. It's width adjusts beautifully with bootstrap but the height doesn't extend as far as I want it, it just stops and then you have whitespace below it.

My guess is if I made an image out of the repeat pattern with like a 1600px height or something and gave a min-height/max-height this might solve but I'd prefer not to. Is there something I'm missing or can try?

So again, just want a sidebar aligned to left of page and another to right of page that can adjust fluidly so that it dissapears or hides behind the container of bootstrap (which is working) but I need it to be a full 100% height of page no matter how much the page stretches.

Comment: If you have control of the CSS, why not set the `background` of `body` to `url("../images/subtle_stripes.png") repeat;` and then set the background of `#container` to white? I'm guessing that your goal is to have the stripes as the background of the page, but not as the background of the container?

Comment: doing this will add a stripe across the bottom i'm guessing and a wider width that I am not trying to achieve and may not work fluidly maybe.

I don't know why but I tried adding classes to the body directly as though they were divs and that lead me to just applying "position:relative;" to body{} . I don't know why this worked but it did??? It doesn't work for the home page, check the home page, but now the sidebars do stretch their width like I had it already and now the height is full except for home page. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. Your last paragraph attempts to explain it, but I don't think "sidebar" is the right term, and I'm not sure what "can adjust fluidly" means. Are you saying you want to prevent the border images from sliding behind your page frame?

Comment: Solved. Those 'sidebars' are just the grey repeat patterns on the left and right ends of page that I've been discussing. I believe adding a position:Relative and some min-heights to my body tag worked and all I need to do is make sure the body of the 'container' on Home page reaches a min-height by filling it with content should fix this problem because it produces only half of the height of the page and the left and ride 'sidebars' follow it.

Comment: Ok, glad it's solved. But you're basically adding loads of markup and unneeded css properties to create a pretend background for the body. If setting the background shows that you have an unwanted space at the bottom of your main container, then you check your margins or sizing on that container, or make sure you've got a min-height set for the container. The body can't be bigger than the content with no reason.

The simplest solutions are always the best ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give

```
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

and

```
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

in css to create repeat pattern.

Comment: Oh sorry, background-image: url("../images/subtle_stripes.png"); is already in repeat, its repeating but not the full length of the page and its outside the container absolutely positioned -.^

Comment: I guess I'll just send the link but not as a URL
www.newreleasewall dot com /primetimegourmet/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=106